# Releasing Semaphores in a Daemon Process

Tags: c, resources, semaphore

I am currently coding a webserver to get better acquainted with processes and interprocess communication.  When a file is requested, I lock it to make sure there are no changes to the file during the read/write.  That works fine.  My issue is how can I clear the lock from memory after the daemon process has finished executing.  I know that semaphores stay around after the process that has created them has stopped executing.  I know the discarding of the semaphore needs to be done in the parent however, the semaphores are created in the child meaning there are no references in the parent.  So basically, it comes down to this: is there a way to reference the semaphores created during the child processes so that I can discard the semaphore in the exit handler when the daemon is stopped?  I don't have code to share because I am truly at a loss for how this can be done.  I am coding in C on a Linux system.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```c
   SemId = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, n, 0600);
```

You are definitely using this to create the semaphores. Here, the `n` is the number of semaphores.

`SemId` can be in the shared memory.

This would allow you to clear the semaphores in the parent.

If you'd like to avoid creation of the global variable and getting the semaphores in the parent or use of the variable in the shared memory, before exiting a child you can definitely use:

```
   semctl(SemId, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
```

The shared memory must be done in the parent and can be done using:

```
   ID = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int) * X, 0600);
```

The size of shared memory is definitely your choice.

```
   SemId = (int *) shmat(ID, NULL, 0);
```

This would attribute the space for the `SemId`. After exiting the child parent can(or any other child) access this variable and delete the semaphores using the `semctl` above.

You have to declare `int *SemID` as a global variable.

So, if the creation of semaphores, the `semget` function is used, you can just return its value to the `SemId` as noted above.

If you decide to use the shared memory option you will have to remember to delete the attributed space of that memory using:

```
  shmdt((void *) SemId);
  shmctl(ID, IPC_RMID, NULL);
```

Comment: okay thanks.  I create a semaphore for each file that is accessed so, I could have as many semaphores as files in the given directory (all created at different times) would clearing the semid be enough to clear all of the semaphores from the children if they are created separately?

Comment: If there are multiple semaphores it means you have several different `SemId`'s. Which means you'll have to call `semctl` for every file.

The easiest solution would be to know the number of files and getting the number of semaphores equal to the number of files in the parent.

If you're testing use `ipcs -s num` and 

`ipcrm -s` to clear any if they're left.

Comment: As a matter of fact when I think about it, you'll just rewrite the `SemId` by creation of new semaphores so, I guess that sometimes you won't be able to delete them.

Are you sure you can't do this using only one semaphore?

Comment: I don't know if i can do it with just one semaphore, this is the first time i've worked with them and they seem very abstract to me at the moment...the way i see it right now is that I need one lock for each file otherwise some files will be safe and others will not be safe

Comment: So, you're using just one file at the time? There's no parallel processing of the files at the same time? I can't figure out the problem and the use of files without the code.
If there's no parallel processing and all the other threads wait for the first one to finish this can be done using one monitor.

Comment: Sorry I must have worded it poorly, there is parallel processing but i only create semaphores as i need them, i thought this would conserve me some resources. would it be better to create a semaphore for each of the files at once?

Comment: Hmm... If there are hundreds of files you'd have to use hundreds of semaphores which to me seems extremely large for this kind of a problem.
What are you doing to the files? If you're reading and writing this still points me to the monitor solution. Where each thread has its own critical section where it writes/reads, then, after finishing the process for the first line, gives a chance for some other thread to do the same.

Comment: I just realized that these complications are meaningless. You can, as stated above, just delete the semaphore in the child if that's what you want.